# Как пропустить если есть в базу mysql

Tags: mysql, циклы

```
foreach (explode(',',$meta_k) as $key) {
    if ($key == $tagss['title']) {continue;} else {mysql_query ("INSERT INTO 
tags (title) VALUES ('$key')");}
}
```

В этот код работает но не пропустить существующий тег. Помогите ребята...

Comment: подозреваю, что в `$tagss['title']` лежит строка с тэгами через запятую. если так, то её тоже надо превратить в массив через `explode`, а потом почитать про `in_array` и поправить проверку внутри `if`.

Comment: пожалуйста дай мне код, я не профессионал, я новичок. Спасибо

Comment: нет, $tagss['title'] не лежит с запитой. Одно целое

Comment: сделай  `print_r($meta_k)` и `print_r($tagss['title'])` и добавь вывод в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$existing_tags = array();

$result = mysql_query('select title from tags');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $existing_tags[] = $row['title'];
};

$meta_k = explode(', ', $meta_k);

foreach ($meta_k as $key => $value) {

    if (in_array($value, $existing_tags)) {
        unset($meta_k[$key]);
    };
};

if (!empty($meta_k)) {

    foreach ($meta_k as $key => $value) {
        $meta_k[$key] = '("'.$value.'")';
    };

    mysql_query('insert into tags (title) values '.implode(', ', $meta_k));
};
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО. КОД РАБОТАЛ...

Comment: @ZohidJo'rayev Сделать поле title в таблице уникальным и использовать `insert ignore into ...` тогда он будет вставлять записи только если их нет. Что будет быстрее чем чтение существующих записей из БД и последующая вставка. И кстати, код в ответе не безопасен, если во время между чтением БД и вставкой другой процесс добавит записи то получите дубль ...